# How to increase Max_execution_time Variable in php/php.ini file

Tags: php, html, xampp

I know this question has been asked soo many times, I have followed some posts and increase the `max_execution_time=300` . The problem i am facing is that after set the limit to 300 it stills shows me the **Fatal Error** if script takes more than 2 minutes in loading.

I have made updates in `xampp/php/php.ini` file

Kindly tell me why its not working properly.

Comment: Can you show your codes? p.s. Apache has timeout limit too.

Comment: Did you restart your server ?

Comment: You've either edited the wrong file (a fairly common issue with Xampp and similar third-party bundles) or the error message is complaining about something different. Please edit the question and: 1) Post the output of `var_dump( ini_get('max_execution_time') );` 2) Post the exact complete error message